# There exists $c$

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a function such that $f'''$ is continuous and $f(0)=f'(0)=f'(1)=0$. Prove that there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that

$$f(1)=-\frac{1}{12} f'''(c)$$

Comment: What is $F$? Or you mean $f$?

Comment: He means $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$.

Comment: @nullUser: I think it is more likely he just means $f$ instead of $F$, but maybe he'll clarify himself.

Comment: In this form, it cannot be true, since if you add $3x^2-2x^3$ to $f$, the initial conditions are preserved, the $LHS$ increases by $1/2$ and the $RHS$ increases by $1$.

Comment: it is $f$, I have edited

Answer (score 2):

If $f(1)\neq 0$, up to rescaling we can assume $f(1)=1$ and
$$ f(x)=3x^2-2x^3+g(x), $$
where $g\in\mathcal{C}^3([0,1])$ satisfies:
$$ g(0)=g'(0)=g(1)=g'(1)=0.$$
In this setting, the statement is equivalent to:
$$ \exists\xi\in(0,1):\;g'''(\xi)=0. $$
If $g$ is constantly zero on $[0,1]$ there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, $|g|$ takes its maximum positive value in $\eta\in(0,1)$, and, by Fermat's theorem, $g'(\eta)=0.$ By Rolle's theorem, there are at least two distinct zeros of $g''(x)$ in $(0,1)$, the first one in $(0,\eta)$ and the latter in $(\eta,1)$.
By Rolle's theorem again, there is a $\xi\in(0,1)$ such that $g'''(\xi)=0$, QED.
If $f(1)=0$, it is sufficient to take $g=f$.